# Pointer to a structure unable to access values of 2D array

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic

I am currently in the process of writing a program that acts as a circuit. I have a gate structure that takes a 2D char array in order to hold variable names, yet when I try to access these variable names stored in the array outside of the while loop, the content is empty.

```
typedef struct Gate
{
    kind_t kind;
    int size;     // size of DECODER and MULTIPLEXER
    char **params; // length determined by kind and size (CHANGED FROM INT TO CHAR)
                  // includes inputs and outputs, indicated by variable numbers
} Gate;

typedef struct Node
{
    Gate *data;
    struct Node *next;
} Node;
```

```
// Linked list of gates & attributes
    while (fscanf(fp, "%16s", str) != EOF)
    {
        if (strcmp(str, "AND") == 0)
        {
            head = makeGate(fp, head, AND);
            length++;
        }
        else if (strcmp(str, "OR") == 0)
        {
            head = makeGate(fp, head, OR);
            length++;
        }
        else if (strcmp(str, "NAND") == 0)
        {
            head = makeGate(fp, head, NAND);
            length++;
        }
        else if (strcmp(str, "NOR") == 0)
        {
            head = makeGate(fp, head, NOR);
            length++;
        }
        else if (strcmp(str, "XOR") == 0)
        {
            head = makeGate(fp, head, XOR);
            length++;
        }
        else if (strcmp(str, "NOT") == 0)
        {
            //head = makeGate(fp, head, NOT);
            //length++;
        }
        else if (strcmp(str, "PASS") == 0)
        {
            //head = makeGate(fp, head, PASS);
            //length++;
        }
        else if (strcmp(str, "DECODER") == 0)
        {
            //
        }
        else if (strcmp(str, "MULTIPLEXER") == 0)
        {
            //
        }
        printf("%s\n", head->data->params[2]);
    }

    // plugs in values to circuit
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        printf("Stored string: %s\n", head->data->params[i]);
    }
```

`

```
Node *makeGate(FILE *fp, Node *head, kind_t inGate)
{
    char str[17];
    Node *new_node = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node)); // Node of linkedlist that contains gate structure
    new_node->data = (Gate *)malloc(sizeof(Gate)); // Gate structure that keeps information about a gate
    new_node->next = head;

    new_node->data->kind = inGate;
    new_node->data->size = 3;
    new_node->data->params = malloc(3 * sizeof(char*));
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        new_node->data->params[i] = malloc(17 * sizeof(char));
    }

    fscanf(fp, "%16s", str);
    new_node->data->params[0] = str;
    fscanf(fp, "%16s", str);
    new_node->data->params[1] = str;
    fscanf(fp, "%16s", str);
    new_node->data->params[2] = str;
    return new_node;
}
```

`
The printf statement inside the while loop works perfectly fine and is there purely for testing, however the for loop that prints each value of the array is different and prints nothing.

I tried to fix this multiple times to no avail, I originally found this problem as I noticed that I had gotten memory leak, and when I freed where the memory leak should be, it throws that I am freeing a address that is not malloced.

My only thought is I am somehow losing/skipping a node, but I am out of ideas

Comment: `new_node->data->params[0] = str;` _etc_... This is _not_ how to copy strings. What you are doing is overwriting the pointers you just allocated (_a.k.a_ leaking memory) and replacing with the pointer `str`, whatever that is. It looks like it's probably a buffer (maybe even local). What you end up with is your entire list contains exactly the same pointer. The contents of that memory are either whatever was last read into that buffer, or is undefined if the memory is no longer on the stack. Some basic experimentation with your debugger would identify this issue pretty much immediately.

Comment: @paddy I see, so to copy I should be using strcpy then. Thank you for the explanation, my professor briefly went over pointers and left most of the class very lost.

Comment: @paddy, quick to the draw, strcpy(&new_node->data->params[0][0], str);  [something like it is needed, provided str is null terminated) or use memcpy.

Comment: A pointer is just a memory location. It's a numeric value. Nothing special really at all. Think of it as a home address. If you bought property at 42 Wallaby Way, Sydney, you can write that address down anywhere. As many copies as you want. But if you want to move in there, you need to pick up your furniture and physically place it in the building. Okay, not the best analogy... Close enough.

Comment: @paddy Who wants to live in a dentist's office? `:-)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following does *not* copy *data* from `str` into the `struct` ( you'd need `strcpy`):

```
new_node->data->params[0] = str;
```

What it does is copy the *address* of `str` into each element. They all point to the *same* buffer/string. And, `str` goes out of scope when the function returns.

You *can* [and *should*] just scan into the struct directly.

So, change:

```
fscanf(fp, "%16s", str);
new_node->data->params[0] = str;

fscanf(fp, "%16s", str);
new_node->data->params[1] = str;

fscanf(fp, "%16s", str);
new_node->data->params[2] = str;
```

Into:

```
fscanf(fp,"%16s",new_node->data->params[0]);
fscanf(fp,"%16s",new_node->data->params[1]);
fscanf(fp,"%16s",new_node->data->params[2]);
```